# SOQL Relationship Query : Compare Child and Parent field value in WHERE clause

Tags: soql, relationships

Is it possible to compare the Child and Parent field values in a **Single SOQL** Relationship Query ?

say get me all contacts for an account which doesn't have same name as its parent account.

```
SELECT Contact.Id, Contact.Name, Account.Id, Account.Name
FROM Contact
WHERE Account.Id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx' AND
      Contact.Name <> Account.Name
```

or get me all opportunities for an account which has same LeadSource as Account

```
SELECT Id, LeadSource, Account.LeadSource
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE AccountId in : accIdSet AND 
LeadSource <> Account.LeadSource
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so. The field expression in the where clause can include only 1 field name and not 2. It must be compared to a native value.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm#fieldexpression

Comment: Thanks @folkert for the answer. I have seen this link before. I should have made it clear in my question that i m looking for possible workarounds..